# Journey Builder Salesforce data entry event contact evaluation/entry

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

Doing some testing using SF data entry event for journey builder and I'm noticing that there are no contacts being evaluated or entered into the journey entry results page.  Is this an intended behavior?

[image]

Even though my burner email is receiving this email and the journey map shows contacts.
[image]

Comment: The entry event interface is quite buggy in general, so I wouldn't trust it. However, it doesn't hurt to log a ticket with Salesforce so they realize again and again that this buggy behavior annoys people.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this a 'known issue' for SFMC or just based on your experience?

Comment: Not aware of any known issue but it is also my experience. Usually we get told to just wait:(

Comment: Is Event data being added to the Data Extension created by the Salesforce Entry Event ?

Comment: Yes - it is @zeljazouli

Comment: @TomCallahan Then the interface is just being buggy. Sometimes you need to wait a little bit !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe the Intended behaviour is that the Entry Event should reflect the number of records processed, but, it can take a while for it to update to reflect actual value.